# Reproducing error from Kubernetes while list / get objects

Tags: kubernetes, operators

In a Kubernetes operator code, I have a snippet that gets/lists obj for the given object key from the Kubernetes Cluster

```
if err := sdk.List(context.TODO(), listObj, listOpts...); err != nil {
    e := fmt.Errorf("failed to list [%s] due to [%s]", listObj.GetObjectKind().GroupVersionKind().Kind, err.Error())
    logger.Error(e, e.Error(), "name", drd.Name, "namespace", drd.Namespace)
```

The get and list are part of the reader interface

```
package client
...
type Reader interface {
    // Get retrieves an obj for the given object key from the Kubernetes Cluster.
    // obj must be a struct pointer so that obj can be updated with the response
    // returned by the Server.
    Get(ctx context.Context, key ObjectKey, obj Object) error

    // List retrieves list of objects for a given namespace and list options. On a
    // successful call, Items field in the list will be populated with the
    // result returned from the server.
    List(ctx context.Context, list ObjectList, opts ...ListOption) error
}
```

I am wondering how do I test the use case where this method throws an error. I am using minikube to run this, but I am not able to test this scenario. Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Have you considered mock objects?

Comment: I did but was wondering how to actually simulate a prod scenario. Maybe I am missing something, i,e. what can cause this error to be triggered